# Displaying value transferred from URL via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, urlparse

I'm having an issue with my codes concerning the transfer of information from one page to another using the url as shown below:

```
window.location.href ="form.html?uname="+uname;
```

The value is displaying in the url box but when I try to display it on the form.html page using the following code:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("uname");
    alert(name);
}
```

The alert keep displaying null.

What is the issue because after an hour of troubleshooting, I can't seem to figure it out.

Is the null being displayed in the alert box means that the value is not being retrieve from the url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query string of the URL of the current page is **not an element**

Comment: Your alert displaying null has nothing to do with passing data between pages. It means you have no element with ID 'uname' at the time the script executes.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById('uname')`

looks for an HTML element with the corresponding id. What you probably want to do is:

```
alert(uname)
```

Comment: `uname` is undefined . You need to parse the url first